# How can I pass an array to a Laravel bind?

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

I have a bunch of bindings set up in my `bootstrap/app.php`. I'm adding a constructor parameter to one of my conretes to make the constructor to look like this:

```
public function __construct(array $names) {
    //Stuff.
}
```

The binding for it is set up as such:

```
$app->singleton(App\Interfaces\SomeInterface::class, App\Config\SomeConcrete::class);
```

I want to specify the array to pass something like this:

```
$app->when(App\Config\SomeConcrete::class)
    ->needs('What goes here??')
    ->give($theArray);
```

I've tried `Array::class` and the parameter name and it doesn't work.

Can I pass an array into a constructor parameter?

Comment: Maybe something like `needs(\ArrayAccess::class)` would work.

Comment: I never thought of `ArrayAccess::class`. I'll try that. I'm new-ish to php: Are there any implications to having my constructor defined as `__constructor(array $array)` while binding the `ArrayAccess` interface? Should I just redefine my constructor to take `ArrayAccess` instead?

Comment: Actually. I don't think `\ArrayAccess` will work now that I think about it, you may need to rewrite a few things. Maybe https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container#container-events would help in this case.

Comment: It doesn't work the way I have it due to the timing of the internal bindings... Ugh, this constant theme of "Rewrite everything" with Laravel.

Comment: To be honest, I find using an `array` as an injected dependency kind of silly.

Comment: @nXu So do I. I would never do this in any other (better) DI framework (read: like Ninject in C#). I should've mentioned that the array is actually Laravel's configuration array obtained with `$app->make('config')` but calling `make('config')` doesn't work anyway because of the where I am in the binding stack. I could probably get around it with Laravel's Facade pattern but adding a bunch of statics everywhere feels gross, couples my code to the static and defeats the purpose of DI.

Comment: Then the real solution is to inject `Illuminate\Config\Repository` instead.

I don't really mind calling the config() helper function though (or using the pseudo-static Config facade). Behind the courtains, it is a well-tested and well-testable (`config(['my_config' => 'mock value'])`) OOP code.

Comment: Trying to solve a different problem I came back to this today... tried to upvote and realized it was my own question. Ho-hum.